# Emulator exited just after reload

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-emulator

I just started my pixel emulator and run my flutter app and it worked correctly but as soon as I updated my code and did ctrl+s (reload) in my vscode then it shows "lost connection to device Exited(sigterm)". What's the issue?[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIqfJ.png)

I tried updating my flutter sdk version by:

```
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
```

but this couldn't help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.